# Are there any built-in or third-party packages for general topology or algebraic topology in Mathematica?

Tags: packages, reference-request, topology

I am learning [general topology (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_topology) and [algebraic topology (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_topology).

> Are there any built-in or third-party packages for general topology or algebraic topology in *Mathematica*?

Through googling, I only found [this article: A Mathematica-package for algebraic braid groups](http://tucs.fi/publications/view/?pub_id=tLukkarila05a).