# Package to generate Braid diagrams

Tags: graphics, reference-request

Are there any packages, built-in or third party, that will allow me to draw custom braids in *Mathematica*? The technical report linked by the question below talks about a package `AlegbraicBraids` and claims that this is available on the website, however this doesn't appear to be the case.

The kinds of diagrams this program produces are perfect:

[image]

Ideally, I would like to be able to reduce eqivalent braids to canonical forms as well, but at the very least I'm looking for some facility to do the actual drawing as above.

Similar to this unanswered question:

[Are there any build-in or third-party packages for general topology or algebraic topology in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66532/are-there-any-build-in-or-third-party-packages-for-general-topology-or-algebraic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update:

I've been working on this and made a package with a single public function: to make these braid diagrams. [Here's a semi-permanent link](https://github.com/Myridium/Mathematica-Paclets/raw/master/Braids-1.0.0.paclet) to the paclet file which can be installed with `PacletInstall` in *Mathematica*.

To load up the package after installing, use `` Needs[Braids`] `` followed by `?BraidDiagram` to see a full description of how to use the `BraidDiagram` function. This is a somewhat outdated example of what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I wonder if there is a newer version of this package

Comment: @yode - there is not.

Answer (score 4):

KnotData does this kind of thing:

```
KnotData[{4, 1}, "BraidImage"]
```

[image]

Comment: I looked at the documentation for `KnotData` and there essentially is none. Looks like it just does a few preset knots?

Comment: If you look at the details section, there are hundreds of kinds of knots and braids, and it supports several different naming conventions.

Comment: Mathematica's documentation is lacklustre. That's why I come here to SE. For example, it says something about the *braid word* notation, but doesn't bother to specify how to use that notation. Simply that it exists. How helpful! Also, *Using KnotData may require internet connectivity.*

Comment: Your question stated: "I'm looking for some facility to do the actual drawing" and this is what I pointed you towards, because you did not indicate that you knew about KnotData. The fact that it needs to access the internet is irrelevant -- accessing StackExchange requires the internet too.